# Offline map for android able to save the users current gps position

Tags: android, offline, maps, gps

I'm searching for an android APP capable off showing a map, getting current GPS position and allowing the user (me) to save the position.

I'll explain my project: I need to place some items in a forest.

- There isn't any data connection (or really really really slow).
- I need to place these items in a regular pattern.
- I need to be able to find these items some months later.

What I don't need (I don't care if it has the features anyway): search or navigation functionalities. There is only forest anyway.

So what I need is a APP with following capabilities:

- Show me the map  (ideally with satellite pictures).
- Download a specified region via WIFI connection.
- Get my GPS position.
- Save many GPS positions (the places where I've placed my items).
- Show the saved positions with a custom circle around it (something between 50m and 120m).
- Show my current position also with a circle around it (ideally in a different colour, but could be the same).

If this kind of tool doesn't exist I will have to write it on my own, but it seems like a lot of work so I'd prefer to use something existing.

Answer (score 2):

[MAPS.ME](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps.pro) seems to fit almost all your needs, except it doesn't show saved locations with circles, but with 'thumbtacks' (see image). Its features are listed here: [maps.me/en/features](http://maps.me/en/features)
Another drawback may affect you: it is not a lightweight app. Besides the offline map data consumes a lot of space (its ok, without satellite pics too), the application also needs circa 80-90 MB on your device, for one this can be a problem.
It also supports exporting/importing saved locations from/to KML and KMZ, thus your saved locations can be used/edited outside the app if you would need it (eg. sharing with others).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Fine, I'll try out, I have about 24GB space on my phone so... space shouldn't be a problem. Exporting and importing is wonderful, I'll use this functionality too.

Comment: I've tried the app, it works fine, but I need the circles to know what area is covered by my items and the satellite view to know where is forest and where only field.

Comment: @Falk you can create any shape in kml (so circles too) and import them with opening from a file manager. Field and forest has different color, feel free to (edit them)[openstreetmaps.org] if necessary, changes will be included in the following update.

Comment: Can I doo all this stuff with the app?